# Delphi listview change header text

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have this simple form:

[image]

and I use this code to add items:

```
FList.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Flist.Items.Clear;

    for LJsonValue in LJsonArr do
      begin
        Item := FList.Items.Add;

        Item.Text := 'some value';

        //What to do?
        FList.??.??.HeaderText := 'Header';
      end;
  finally
    FList.EndUpdate;
  end;
```

How can I change the header and the footer? I have been able to google only the above solution. The above code only sets `some value` instead of `Item Text` but I cannot change `Header Text` and `Footer Text`.

Answer (score 4):

Headers and footers are regular instances of `TListViewItem` except they have their `Purpose` property set to `TListItemPurpose.Header` or `TListItemPurpose.Footer`. This property instructs the component to render those items using special appearances - see
properties [ItemAppearance](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.ListView.TAppearanceListView.ItemAppearance) and [ItemAppearanceObjects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.ListView.TAppearanceListView.ItemAppearanceObjects) of `TListView`.

You can add header(s) and footer(s) at run-time (assumed using standard appearance):

```
Item := Flist.Items.Add;
Item.Text := 'Header';
Item.Purpose := TListItemPurpose.Header;

Flist.Items.Add.Text := 'Item 1';
Flist.Items.Add.Text := 'Item 2';

Item := Flist.Items.Add;
Item.Text := 'Footer';
Item.Purpose := TListItemPurpose.Footer;
```

Comment: Am I adding a custom header/footer for each item in the list in this way?

Comment: @RosannaTrevisan: It's possible, but not necessary. Those special items are rather designed to be group headers and footers for the normal items they surround.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TFrmPrincipal.AddHeader(categoria: string);
var
  item: TListViewItem;
begin
  item := lvProdutos.Items.Add;
  item.Purpose := TListItemPurpose.Header;
  item.Text := categoria;
end;
```

Credit to: 99Coders (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2qEEhn_2Tc).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Please try to answer the question. Posting own black-box code in hardly ever does that .